# Google Drive API copy() - 404 error

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using Google Drive API in PHP to manage any files (insert, delete, copy..).
Now I need to create a copy of a file in drive folder (insert work fine).
My code is the same of Google [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy#examples). I'm find the file ID with search parameters and then call the function:

```
$parameters = array();
$parameters['q'] = "title = '".$title."' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'";
$files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
if (count($files['items'])>0){
    $fileId = $files['items'][0]['id']; // unique file name
    $copiedFile = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $copiedFile->setTitle("copied_file");
    $service->files->copy($fileId, $copiedFile);
}
```

but when I call copy() I got this error:

```
 Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1adQjO5ABcbTai3GAEU3RBRHGi8u0_7DlaZfgWywxvqk/copy: (404) File not found: 16bRhq0E_OqYQlTys1oFu1vVeAjWl1P_non2-Z3lLdb8
```

This is the right id of the file to copy:

```
1adQjO5ABcbTai3GAEU3RBRHGi8u0_7DlaZfgWywxvqk
```

but what's this id:

```
16bRhq0E_OqYQlTys1oFu1vVeAjWl1P_non2
```

How can i solve it ?

Comment: Does the file exists? Additionally, do you have permissions for the file? I check on the get method for this id, and I receive the same issue (404), mentioning that the file does not exist. I do not get the other ID though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now It works. I logout from my application (and delete from google account permission): when I logged in google OAuth request new permission and It work fine.